# Expression's integral domain

Tags: calculus

Given the next expression:

$$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x^2}{e^{-2\sqrt{t}}}dt$$

How can i calculate its domain? I figured that it was related to its derivative, but not sure how to get there.

Help? Thanks

Comment: i've edited, thanks

Comment: This is defined for any real $x$.

Comment: Do you mean the domain of $t$? It's from 0 to a positive real number $x^2$. If you want to solve the integral substitute $t=y^2$.

Comment: You are not given a function. You are given an expression. The question is: For which real numbers $x$ is the expression defined?

Comment: take a look [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Function_is_Riemann_Integrable)

Comment: @Agapita An "integral domain" is sadly not the domain of an integral; it's a kind of ring. (The word "integral" here means "a bit like the integers".) Accordingly I have removed that tag.

Answer (score 0):

To find the domain of $f(x)$, we will begin by evaluating the integral.
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=\int_0^{x^2}e^{-2\sqrt t}dt \\
&=\int_0^x2ue^{-2u}du;t=u^2 \\
&=\left(ue^{-2u}+\frac 12e^{-2u}\right)_0^x \\
&=\left(xe^{-2x}+\frac 12e^{-2x}\right)-\left(\frac 12e^0\right) \\
&=xe^{-2x}+\frac 12e^{-2x}-\frac 12.
\end{aligned}$$
This is clearly defined over all of $\mathbb R$.